# Mapstruct different mappers for the same target class

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have this entity:

```
public class Character {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String image;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "characters_movies",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "character"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie")
    )
    private List<Movie> movies;
```

And this DTO for that entity:

```
public class CharacterDTO extends AbstractResponse{
    
    private int id;
    private String image;
    private String name;
    private List<MovieDTO> movies;

    public CharacterDTO(String image, String name){
        this.image= image;
        this.name= name;
    }
}
```

And this mapper:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = MovieMapper.class)
public interface CharacterMapper {

    List<CharacterDTO> toCharactersDTO(List<Character> characters);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration(name = "toCharacterDTO")
    Character toCharacter(CharacterDTO characterDTO);

    default CharacterDTO toCharacterDTO(Character character, String o){
        return new CharacterDTO(character.getImage(), character.getName());
    }

    default CharacterDTO toCharacterDTO(Character character){
        return new CharacterDTO(character.getImage(), character.getName(), character.getAge(), character.getWeight(), character.getHistory(), null);
    }
    
}
```

I have 2 methods for mapper to the DTO, because in some cases i do not want to show the id. This approach works (i do not if there is a better one), but i want to specify to the toCharactersDTO to use the method with 2 parameters. Any idea i can do that?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like that:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = MovieMapper.class)
public interface CharacterMapper {

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "toDTO")
    List<CharacterDTO> toCharactersDTO(List<Character> characters);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration(name = "toCharacterDTO")
    Character toCharacter(CharacterDTO characterDTO);

    // unused parameter "o"
    @Named("toDTO")
    CharacterDTO toDTO(Character character/*, String o*/){
        return new CharacterDTO(character.getImage(), character.getName());
    }

    default CharacterDTO toCharacterDTO(Character character){
        return new CharacterDTO(character.getImage(), character.getName(), character.getAge(), character.getWeight(), character.getHistory(), null);
    }
    
}
```